# Remove first page from DOM in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using JQM 1.3.2 and 1 page per html file. JQM automatically removes pages from the DOM that are loaded by AJAX. But there is a known issue (clearly stated in the docs and frequently discussed in various forums) where the first page is not removed. I'm wondering if there are any potential pitfalls with this workaround:

```
$(document).on('pageshow.firstPageRemoval', function (event, data) {
    if (data.prevPage.length > 0) {
        data.prevPage.remove();
        $(document).off('pageshow.firstPageRemoval');
    }
});
```

From my brief testing, it seems to be working as designed. The first page loads, and data.prevPage.length === 0, so it does nothing. After the next page transition, it removes the first page and removes the handler.

My question is, are there any issues that might crop up because I've removed the first page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only issue is browser history, basically you will remove page but it will still stay in history.

Of course there's a workaround. Instead of removing first page, don't have one in the first place.

Let your first HTML be blank, and load external page during that page document ready state. Unfortunately you will not be able to use **pageinit** (or similar page event here) because you will not have initial page to trigger it.

This way you will circumvent this problem and browser history will stay clean and intact.